# xsl:copy-of and xsl:attribute in one template

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've got quite a complex question (IMO) so I hope it will be clear what I mean.

Consider the XML with the following structure.

```
<products>
    <product exportName="XPOZER_90X120">
      <product-options>
        <option productOptionRef="xpozerFrame">
          <plan>
            <period startDate="2015-10-01">
              <price name="true" netBasePrice="34"/>
              <price name="false" netBasePrice="0"/>
            </period>
          </plan>
        </option>
      </product-options>
    </product>
</products>
```

This product has two "price" child nodes. 
It needs to be transformed into one "product" node for every "price" childnode there is and at the same time exportName attribute must be changed into a generated value. The rest of the nodes stay the same.

The desired output:

```
<products>
    <product exportName="XPOZER_WITHFRAME90X120">
      <product-options>
        <option productOptionRef="xpozerFrame">
          <plan>
            <period startDate="2015-10-01">
              <price name="true" netBasePrice="34"/>
              <price name="false" netBasePrice="0"/>
            </period>
          </plan>
        </option>
      </product-options>
    </product>
    <product exportName="XPOZER_NOFRAME90X120">
      <product-options>
        <option productOptionRef="xpozerFrame">
          <plan>
            <period startDate="2015-10-01">
              <price name="true" netBasePrice="34"/>
              <price name="false" netBasePrice="0"/>
            </period>
          </plan>
        </option>
      </product-options>
    </product>
</products>
```

exportname becomes 'XPOZER_NOFRAME90X120' and 'XPOZER_WITHFRAME90X120' and they are calculated with the document function in the same xslt and then doing some transformations.

I've got the product node transformations working but I'm stuck on changing the exportName attribute. The value that it must become is working already but I dont know how to actually change the exportName attribute while doing a copy.

This the xslt so far

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
        xmlns:input="urn:input-variables"
        xmlns:my="my:my">
          <my:values>
            <xpozerFramefalse>NOFRAME</xpozerFramefalse>
            <xpozerFrametrue>WITHFRAME</xpozerFrametrue>
            <XPOZER_90X120>XPOZER_[xpozerFrame]90X120</XPOZER_90X120>
          </my:values>

  <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>


              <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="products/product[@exportName='XPOZER_90X120']" />
              </xsl:template>  

              <xsl:template match="product[product-options/option/plan/period/price]">
                <xsl:for-each select="product-options/option/plan/period/price">
                    <xsl:variable name="vNewExportName">
                      <xsl:call-template name="priceNode" />
                    </xsl:variable>         
                    <xsl:copy-of select="../../../../.." />
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:template>

              <xsl:template name="priceNode">

               <xsl:variable name="vProductOptionRef" select="../../../@productOptionRef" />
                <xsl:variable name="vSelector" select="concat($vProductOptionRef, @name)" />
                <xsl:variable name="vExportname" select="../../../../../@exportName" />
                <xsl:variable name="vNewExportName">
                    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="document('')//my:values/*[name()=$vExportname]" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="concat(concat('[', $vProductOptionRef), ']')" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="document('')//my:values/*[name()=$vSelector]" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="$vNewExportName" />
              </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the for-each with copy-of takes care of copying the node twice into the transformed XML and the value that exportname should be changed into is found correctly by retrieving the values from "my:values". 
But I really don't know how to apply the value to the actual attribute.

Can anybody help me with this? is this even possible without falling back on coding?

Comment: Can you 1) explain how to compute the exportName 2) and provide us a sample expected output? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edited in response to clarifications:***

As far as I can tell, you want to do something like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="my:my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<my:values>
    <xpozerFramefalse>NOFRAME</xpozerFramefalse>
    <xpozerFrametrue>WITHFRAME</xpozerFrametrue>
    <XPOZER_90X120>XPOZER_[xpozerFrame]90X120</XPOZER_90X120>
</my:values>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="product[product-options]">
    <xsl:for-each select="product-options/option/plan/period/price">
        <xsl:variable name="exportName" select="ancestor::product/@exportName" />
        <xsl:variable name="productOptionRef" select="ancestor::option/@productOptionRef" />
        <xsl:variable name="lookup-values" select="document('')//my:values/*" />
        <xsl:variable name="replace-src" select="concat($productOptionRef, @name)"/>

        <xsl:variable name="newExportName">
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$lookup-values[name()=$exportName]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="search-string" select="concat('[', $productOptionRef, ']')"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace-string" select="$lookup-values[name()=$replace-src]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <product exportName="{$newExportName}">
            <product-options>
                <option productOptionRef="{$productOptionRef}">
                    <plan>
                        <period startDate="{../@startDate}">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                        </period>
                    </plan>
                </option>
          </product-options>
        </product>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="search-string"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace-string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, $search-string)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $search-string)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replace-string"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $search-string)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="search-string" select="$search-string"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace-string" select="$replace-string"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result here will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
   <product exportName="XPOZER_WITHFRAME90X120">
      <product-options>
         <option productOptionRef="xpozerFrame">
            <plan>
               <period startDate="2015-10-01">
                  <price name="true" netBasePrice="34"/>
               </period>
            </plan>
         </option>
      </product-options>
   </product>
   <product exportName="XPOZER_NOFRAME90X120">
      <product-options>
         <option productOptionRef="xpozerFrame">
            <plan>
               <period startDate="2015-10-01">
                  <price name="false" netBasePrice="0"/>
               </period>
            </plan>
         </option>
      </product-options>
   </product>
</products>
```

Note: I would suggest using a [key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) to lookup the values from `my:values`.

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen You need to provide some clear rules regarding the logic that needs to be applied here. Non-working code (with a missing template!) is not a good guide.

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen Also indicate if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen I am afraid that still makes no sense. Please explain - in words - how to get from "XPOZER_90X120" to "XPOZER_WITHFRAME90X120", step by step. Note also that your code refers to `@productOptionRef`, but no such attribute appears in your XML.

Comment: The values of exportname actually don't matter, they are correctly calculated. The question is about how to actually get the value into exportName. But I added in the productOptionRef attribute

Comment: "*The values of exportname actually don't matter, they are correctly calculated.*" I don't see that. I try to run your code but I get an error `template string-replace-all not found`.

Comment: aaaah ok! Yeah I snipped what I thought was the irrelevant parts. Now it should to the transformation up till the point where I'm stuck

Comment: yep that's exactly what has to be done! Big thanks! Some other nice techniques in there I didn't know about so that also helps